# Mysql INSERT SET type

Tags: php, mysql, set, sql-insert

Sorry for my English but it is not my native language.
I have created a user interface to insert data to MySQL. Everything except one thing is ok but when I want to read data from multiple checkboxes and write them to SET type in MySQL it just doesn't work. I have tried to find the answer but after 4 hours I can't find it or I don't understand it.

http://jyxo.info/uploads/21/21b104df77f6ca723bb708d8d0549af5430e8e91.jpg

dobaVyskytu is SET type and there are in with month you can find mushroom(my tema is online atlas of mushrooms)

in user interfacei have 12 checkbox for 12 month.

http://jyxo.info/uploads/FD/fd548760b155307dfa677ada7c4be4996abf7b93.png

In dobavyskytu i need to have multiple select and that is reason why i use $doba +=

```
if(isset($_POST["Leden"]))
{
    $doba += "Leden";
}

if(isset($_POST["Únor"]))
{
    $doba += "Únor";
}

if(isset($_POST["Březen"]))
{
    $doba += "Březen";
}


Db::query("INSERT INTO houby(nazev,dobaVyskytu,mistoVyskytu,popis,jedovatost,img)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)",$nazev,$doba,$misto,$popis,$jedovatost,$foto);
```

Thank you all for reading and for help because it works now.

Comment: Take a look at [ask]. You should describe what happens, what you expect to happen, how they differ and preferably, provide an [MCVE]

Comment: $doba is your SET field? Why do you use `$doba += "Únor"` instead of `$doba = "Únor"`?

Comment: Do you use PHP?

Comment: Show the  Db::query function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For strings in PHP, it uses `.` as concatanation not `+`, so

```
$doba .= "Leden";
```

Edit:
For a better way of doing this, you should try something like...

```
$options = [];
if(isset($_POST["Leden"]))
{
    $options[] = "Leden";
}

if(isset($_POST["Únor"]))
{
    $options[] = "Únor";
}
...
$doba = implode(',', $options);
```

As this will give you something like `Leden,Únor`

Comment: when i do that a get message Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in /w/halama/mysql/houby/library.php on line 37 and thats where is $options = [];

Comment: Depends on the version of PHP - change it to `$options = array();`

Answer (score 0):

My hypotheses are:

- $doba is the variable you want to insert in your SET type column (I translated and it seems the values you put as example in your question is Slovak for "January", "February", "March" -- I suppose there could be more).
- I suppose that your SET type column is "dobaVyskytu" and that you created it correctly in MySQL by including all the possible values in the column definition.

(Your question update seem to confirm my hypotheses!)

First, when you want to insert multiple values in a SET type column in MySQL, the string value has to be separated with commas.

With the code I see, you can end up with that string "LedenÚnorBřezen" (I suppose you use += for string concatenation, but you should really use .= like Nigel Ren mentionned).  You really want to end up with a string like "Leden,Únor,Březen" if all the 3 values you show are checked in your form.

See here for how to handle SET type in MySQL:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html

Since you do not know if you will end up with 0 or multiple values for that column, I would suggest to make $doba an array.

```
$doba = array(); // depending on your PHP version, you can also write $doba = [];
```

After, you can add your values this way (the syntax $array[] = 'value' will apprend a value to the array):

```
$doba[] = "Leden";
$doba[] = "Únor";
$doba[] = "Březen";
```

Then, before inserting it, you can convert the array to a string with the values separated by commas that way:

```
$csvDoba = implode(',', $doba);
```

Then use $csvDoba instead of $doba in your Db::query() line.

---

After you get this working, here are more things you can look for to improve your code:

- You can also take advantage PHP magic by naming your form checkbox with a special name to avoid repeating yourself.

  For example, you can name all your checkboxes with the name "doba[]", and if (isset($_POST["doba"]), it will already be an array with all the checked values!  But beware, if no value is checked, it won't be set.  That way, you will avoid doing an if condition for each of your checkbox.

  You can do something like this in your code to retrieve the value:

  $doba = isset($_POST['doba']) ? (array) $_POST['doba'] : array();

  What this do?

  If any checkboxes named "doba[]" is checked, then you will retrieve them and make sure the value you retrieve is of type array, the "(array)" part for the value to be an array even if it was not (e.g., an error or someone trying to hack your form).  Else you will return an empty array (as no choices has been put).

  If you are not familar with this syntax, do a searcch for "ternary operator".
- You will of course want to do some validation of your values if not already done
- You might look to put the values in another table instead of using the "SET type", but that is up to you and at this stade you probably still have a couple stuff to learn, so I don't want to flood you with too much info. ;-)